# Passing values through pipes

Tags: command-line, pipe

I don't quite understand pipes in Linux command line.

I noticed that:

```
ll - R | grep *.pdf
```

will list files ending with  `.pdf`

But

```
locate *.pdf | du -h
```

will not calculate the size of files ending with `.pdf`. Rather it will list the size of files in the current directory.

What is going wrong here?

What I have in mind is the output of the first command is the input of the next.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Pipes work by sending one program's output to another program's input. This means that the program receiving the output of the other has to be able to read from `STDIN` ([standard streams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams)).

In this case, `grep` is able to read the output of `ll` because it is designed that way. `du` expects a command line argument pointing to the directory it should run in (if a directory isn't given, it will default to the current working directory `./`).

As for seeing the sizes of the `.pdf` files, if all the files are in a directory, you can run `du -h -d1 /path/to/pdf/dir` or `locate *.pdf | xargs | du -h`. If they are in different directories, you will want to use `-exec` and `find` together (another user will probably give you a hand with this, I'm not quite sure how to do it).

Comment: By the way, can you give me some example commands that are designed to read from `STDIN`

Comment: Instead of `du -h -d1 /path/to/pdf/dir`, it is also possible to use `locate *.pdf | xargs | du -h`

Comment: @bbaja42 thanks, I'll add that to the post.

Comment: @bbaja42 There's one too many `|` characters there.  try `locate *.pdf | xargs du -h` instead (i.e. no `|` between `xargs` and `du`).  Also, if any of the filenames contain spaces or newlines, it's safer to use `locate -0 *.pdf | xargs -0 -r du -h` (assuming your `locate` is actually `mlocate` or some other `locate` that has the `-0` option).  Finally, this won't work correctly if there any `.pdf` files in the current directory because the shell will expand the glob before passing it to `locate` - use `locate -0 .pdf` instead.

Answer (score 2):

> What I have in mind is the output of the first command is the input of the next.

That is correct. However, in your two examples, the difference is that `grep` acts on its input whereas `du` does not. Piping works as expected only if the first command gives something to the **standard output** and the second takes something from the **standard input**, in which case thes two flows will be connected through a "pipe". You can find out if this is possible by looking for "standard input" and "standard output" in the man pages of the commands.

Comment: I do not quite understand why `grep` acts on its input whereas `du` does not. How can judge that `grep` can while `du` can not. Or given another program, how can I determine whether it can or not act on its input?

Comment: Both `man grep` and `grep --help` tell you in the first lines that standard input is accepted by this command. This should be the case for any command accepting `STDIN`.